# Can't remove sharepoint hosted add-in from site collection

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've installed a sharepoint hosted add-in to a site collection and am trying to remove it from the site collection.  When I go to Site Contents and click the ellipses (...) beside the application, the popup menu only has 'Details', 'Monitor', and 'Manage Permissions' options - no remove options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the 'Return to classic SharePoint' link , now try again click the ellipses (...) beside the application.

Comment: Oh wow.... that did it!